# Python Tkinter widgets added to root window instead of Toplevel window

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Using Python 2.7 here. I am trying to add a basic settings window, but when I open a Toplevel window and try to add widgets to it, the widgets get added to the main window instead. Here is an example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class MainWindow (tk.Frame):
    def __init__ (self, root):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.root = root
        self.root.geometry("300x200")
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Settings", command=self.open_settings).pack()

    def open_settings (self):
        settings_win = tk.Toplevel(self.root, height=300, width=400)
        settings_win.focus_set()

        top_frame = tk.Frame(settings_win, bg="red").pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        bottom_frame = tk.Frame(settings_win, bg="blue").pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)

        top_label = tk.Label(top_frame, text="Top Label").pack()
        bottom_label = tk.Label(bottom_frame, text="Bottom Label").pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    MainWindow(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Here is what I see when I click on the **Settings** button below. The second window opens but the labels show up on the main window.

[image]

Comment: Have you done any debugging? I suspect that `top_frame` is not being set to what you think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its because your packing on the same line, check out the answer to this question, he explains it in detail: [Python - Tkinter - Widgets created inside a class inherited from Toplevel() appear in a different frame OUTSIDE the class, Toplevel() class is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328346/python-tkinter-widgets-created-inside-a-class-inherited-from-toplevel-appe)

this should fix it:

```
    top_frame = tk.Frame(settings_win, bg="red")
    top_frame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    bottom_frame = tk.Frame(settings_win, bg="blue")
    bottom_frame.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)

    top_label = tk.Label(top_frame, text="Top Label")
    top_label.pack()
    bottom_label = tk.Label(bottom_frame, text="Bottom Label")
    bottom_label.pack()
```

here is a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: You are right. I love you.

Comment: np, anytime mate